# ZDCChatView scrollToLast iOS app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, zendesk

My application getting crash with zendesk. I am getting crashes on daily basis. I did not find an solution over the github of Zendesk itself.

Zendesk SDK for mobile is a quick, convenient way to get customer support into your mobile apps. With just a few lines of code, you can provide your end users with an easy way to get in touch from any mobile app.

> Error: Fatal Exception: NSRangeException-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]: row (12) beyond bounds (12) for section (0).

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by pankaj bhardwaj at Tue, 08 May 2018 07:32:39 GMT

# Organization: ******** India
# Platform: ios
# Application: *********
# Version: 2.1.3 (1)
# Bundle Identifier: 
# Issue #: 331
# Issue ID: 5a0f0cfc61b02d480da67f98
# Session ID: 4c850433743442f89d7c9f7cef51f414_DNE_0_v2
# Date: 2018-05-08T07:28:00Z
# OS Version: 11.3.1 (15E302)
# Device: iPhone 6s
# RAM Free: 2.4%
# Disk Free: 36.9%

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  myApp                      0x105121578 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4377040248
1  myApp                      0x105121578 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4377040248
2  myApp                      0x105121434 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4377039924
3  myApp                      0x105111174 CLSHandler + 4376973684
4  myApp                      0x10511f580 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4377032064
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x184bcd640 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  myApp                      0x10511f014 CLSExceptionRecord + 4377030676
8  myApp                      0x10511ee3c CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4377030204
9  myApp                      0x10511ea50 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4377029200
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x18447d37c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x18447cccc __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 130
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18448c720 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 362
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1852d2c6c -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 114
14 UIKit                          0x18f30e364 -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:] + 1856
15 UIKit                          0x18f30e98c -[UITableView _scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:usingPresentationValues:] + 152
16 UIKit                          0x18f22412c -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 148
17 myApp                      0x10527d368 -[ZDCChatView scrollToLast:] (ZDCChatView.m:640)
18 myApp                      0x105260880 __41-[ZDCChatViewController keyboardDidShow:]_block_invoke (ZDCChatViewController.m:337)
19 UIKit                          0x18ee9b3d4 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 608
20 UIKit                          0x18ee9b158 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 108
21 myApp                      0x1052607bc -[ZDCChatViewController keyboardDidShow:] (ZDCChatViewController.m:340)
22 CoreFoundation                 0x185264c3c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1852641b8 _CFXRegistrationPost + 428
24 CoreFoundation                 0x185263f14 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 216
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1852e184c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408
26 CoreFoundation                 0x18519af38 _CFXNotificationPost + 384
27 Foundation                     0x185c0bbbc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
28 UIKit                          0x18f06a90c -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 1628
29 UIKit                          0x18f0638e4 -[UIInputWindowController mergeTransitionIfNecessaryWithTransition:] + 280
30 UIKit                          0x18f063174 -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 372
31 UIKit                          0x18f0589c8 -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 1104
32 UIKit                          0x18f0528a4 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 56
33 UIKit                          0x18f04efe8 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1716
34 UIKit                          0x1a52d4e9c -[UIPeripheralHostAccessibility setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 76
35 UIKit                          0x18eeab6ac -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 2472
36 UIKit                          0x18f066d68 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 276
37 UIKit                          0x18f066a18 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 312
38 UIKit                          0x18f103fb0 -[UITextView resignFirstResponder] + 96
39 UIKit                          0x1a5285ee0 -[UITextViewAccessibility resignFirstResponder] + 48
40 UIKit                          0x18f103e9c -[UITextView setEditable:] + 80
41 Apptimize                      0x105842ecc __ABTSwizzleDynamicSelectorProperty_block_invoke_5 + 520
42 myApp                      0x10527d0d4 -[ZDCChatView setTimedOut:] (ZDCChatView.m:587)
43 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4b24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
44 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
45 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bd16e0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
46 CoreFoundation                 0x18527b070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
47 CoreFoundation                 0x185278bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
48 CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
49 GraphicsServices               0x18717b020 GSEventRunModal + 100
50 UIKit                          0x18f17978c UIApplicationMain + 236
51 myApp                      0x104d65520 main (main.m:16)
52 libdyld.dylib                  0x184c29fc0 start + 4

--

Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1852d2d8c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18448c5ec objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1852d2c6c -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  UIKit                          0x18f30e364 -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]
4  UIKit                          0x18f30e98c -[UITableView _scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:usingPresentationValues:]
5  UIKit                          0x18f22412c -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]
6  myApp                      0x10527d368 -[ZDCChatView scrollToLast:] (ZDCChatView.m:640)
7  myApp                      0x105260880 __41-[ZDCChatViewController keyboardDidShow:]_block_invoke (ZDCChatViewController.m:337)
8  UIKit                          0x18ee9b3d4 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
9  UIKit                          0x18ee9b158 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]
10 myApp                      0x1052607bc -[ZDCChatViewController keyboardDidShow:] (ZDCChatViewController.m:340)
11 CoreFoundation                 0x185264c3c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1852641b8 _CFXRegistrationPost
13 CoreFoundation                 0x185263f14 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1852e184c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:]
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18519af38 _CFXNotificationPost
16 Foundation                     0x185c0bbbc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
17 UIKit                          0x18f06a90c -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:]
18 UIKit                          0x18f0638e4 -[UIInputWindowController mergeTransitionIfNecessaryWithTransition:]
19 UIKit                          0x18f063174 -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]
20 UIKit                          0x18f0589c8 -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]
21 UIKit                          0x18f0528a4 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:]
22 UIKit                          0x18f04efe8 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:]
23 UIKit                          0x1a52d4e9c -[UIPeripheralHostAccessibility setInputViews:animationStyle:]
24 UIKit                          0x18eeab6ac -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]
25 UIKit                          0x18f066d68 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder]
26 UIKit                          0x18f066a18 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder]
27 UIKit                          0x18f103fb0 -[UITextView resignFirstResponder]
28 UIKit                          0x1a5285ee0 -[UITextViewAccessibility resignFirstResponder]
29 UIKit                          0x18f103e9c -[UITextView setEditable:]
30 Apptimize                      0x105842ecc (Missing)
31 myApp                      0x10527d0d4 -[ZDCChatView setTimedOut:] (ZDCChatView.m:587)
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4b24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4ae4 _dispatch_client_callout
34 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bd16e0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
35 CoreFoundation                 0x18527b070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
36 CoreFoundation                 0x185278bc8 __CFRunLoopRun
37 CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
38 GraphicsServices               0x18717b020 GSEventRunModal
39 UIKit                          0x18f17978c UIApplicationMain
40 myApp                      0x104d65520 main (main.m:16)
41 libdyld.dylib                  0x184c29fc0 start

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  myApp                      0x105121578 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4377040248
1  myApp                      0x105121578 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4377040248
2  myApp                      0x105121434 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4377039924
3  myApp                      0x105111174 CLSHandler + 4376973684
4  myApp                      0x10511f580 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4377032064
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x184bcd640 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  myApp                      0x10511f014 CLSExceptionRecord + 4377030676
8  myApp                      0x10511ee3c CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4377030204
9  myApp                      0x10511ea50 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4377029200
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x18447d37c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x18447cccc __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 130
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18448c720 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 362
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1852d2c6c -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 114
14 UIKit                          0x18f30e364 -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:] + 1856
15 UIKit                          0x18f30e98c -[UITableView _scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:usingPresentationValues:] + 152
16 UIKit                          0x18f22412c -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 148
17 myApp                      0x10527d368 -[ZDCChatView scrollToLast:] (ZDCChatView.m:640)
18 myApp                      0x105260880 __41-[ZDCChatViewController keyboardDidShow:]_block_invoke (ZDCChatViewController.m:337)
19 UIKit                          0x18ee9b3d4 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 608
20 UIKit                          0x18ee9b158 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 108
21 myApp                      0x1052607bc -[ZDCChatViewController keyboardDidShow:] (ZDCChatViewController.m:340)
22 CoreFoundation                 0x185264c3c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1852641b8 _CFXRegistrationPost + 428
24 CoreFoundation                 0x185263f14 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 216
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1852e184c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408
26 CoreFoundation                 0x18519af38 _CFXNotificationPost + 384
27 Foundation                     0x185c0bbbc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
28 UIKit                          0x18f06a90c -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 1628
29 UIKit                          0x18f0638e4 -[UIInputWindowController mergeTransitionIfNecessaryWithTransition:] + 280
30 UIKit                          0x18f063174 -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 372
31 UIKit                          0x18f0589c8 -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 1104
32 UIKit                          0x18f0528a4 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 56
33 UIKit                          0x18f04efe8 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1716
34 UIKit                          0x1a52d4e9c -[UIPeripheralHostAccessibility setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 76
35 UIKit                          0x18eeab6ac -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 2472
36 UIKit                          0x18f066d68 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 276
37 UIKit                          0x18f066a18 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 312
38 UIKit                          0x18f103fb0 -[UITextView resignFirstResponder] + 96
39 UIKit                          0x1a5285ee0 -[UITextViewAccessibility resignFirstResponder] + 48
40 UIKit                          0x18f103e9c -[UITextView setEditable:] + 80
41 Apptimize                      0x105842ecc __ABTSwizzleDynamicSelectorProperty_block_invoke_5 + 520
42 myApp                      0x10527d0d4 -[ZDCChatView setTimedOut:] (ZDCChatView.m:587)
43 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4b24 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
44 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bc4ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
45 libdispatch.dylib              0x184bd16e0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
46 CoreFoundation                 0x18527b070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
47 CoreFoundation                 0x185278bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
48 CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
49 GraphicsServices               0x18717b020 GSEventRunModal + 100
50 UIKit                          0x18f17978c UIApplicationMain + 236
51 myApp                      0x104d65520 main (main.m:16)
52 libdyld.dylib                  0x184c29fc0 start + 4

#1. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18527ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x185278908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x185c0d674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x185c0d51c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7  UIKit                          0x18ee5e7e4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x185d1defc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#2. GAIThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18527ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x185278908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x185c0d674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x185c821a8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  myApp                      0x105078980 +[GAI threadMain:] + 4376349056
8  Foundation                     0x185d1defc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#3. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d590f4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184efbc90 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18441025c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x18c8ef1a4 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 104
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x18c8eedb8 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 164
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x18c8eeb60 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&) + 10
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x18c8eef7c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 44
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#4. WebThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18527ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x185278908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  WebCore                        0x18d425d9c RunWebThread(void*) + 592
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#5. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37c80 mach_msg + 72
2  myApp                      0x10510c044 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4376952900
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#6. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18527ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x185278908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  CFNetwork                      0x185aa64b0 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
6  Foundation                     0x185d1defc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#7. TAGThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d37c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18527ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x185278908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x185198da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x185c0d674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x185c821a8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  myApp                      0x1050af794 +[TAGDispatchUtil threadMain:] + 4376573844
8  Foundation                     0x185d1defc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#8. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d59538 __select + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x185283378 __CFSocketManager + 644
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9220 _pthread_body + 272
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef9110 _pthread_body + 290
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b10 thread_start + 4

#9. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d59d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b08 start_wqthread + 4

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d59d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef80a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1420
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b08 start_wqthread + 4

#11. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d59d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b08 start_wqthread + 4

#12. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d59d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef80a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1420
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b08 start_wqthread + 4

#13. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d59d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b08 start_wqthread + 4

#14. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b04 start_wqthread + 122

#15. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x184d59d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef80a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1420
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ef7b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Any solution would be help full to remove this crash. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seem like it's a bug from Zendesk SDK and they haven't fixed it yet. You can take a look at this issue https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_sdk_chat_ios/issues/152

Comment: The reason is that, your library tries to scroll to the cell at index 12 (which is the 13th element of the list) when it has only 12 elements. And as the list index starts from 0, then application crashes. As it come from the code of ZDChatView: `[ZDCChatView scrollToLast:]`, you have to wait the fix from the team or you can fork the library somewhere and fix it your self